# How do I make it so that the developer console for excel doesn't display after running an Excel Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

After lots of research and other helpful people on this site I have been able to get my excel macro to run perfectly without any help. I would appreciate some help with one small detail that I haven't been able to find an answer to anywhere:

My workbook runs my VBA macro automatically when it opens, but when the macro is complete, it takes the user's display to the VBA Developer console. I would like for this not to happen so that the user just stays on sheet1. I tried adding: `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` to the end of the sub but that didn't seem to do anything.

This behavior is not specific to this macro and as far as I know happens every time.

Thank you for any advise you may have.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

Dim titleColumn As Integer 'Column of user story title
Dim descriptionColumn As Integer 'Column of user story description
Dim duedateColumn As Integer 'Column of when assignment is due
Dim startRow As Integer 'The row that the first homework assignment is found on the Word table (usually 2)

Dim eTitleRow As Long 'excel row index for Title
Dim eDescriptionRow As Long 'excel row index for Description
Dim eDueDateRow As Long 'excel row index for Duedate
Dim mTitleRow As Long 'word row index for Title
Dim mDescriptionRow As Long 'word row index for Description
Dim mDueDateRow As Long 'word row index for Duedate


wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc;*.docx),*.doc;*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
        startRow = startRowinput.Value
        TableNo = TableNoinput.Value
        titleColumn = titleColumninput.Value
        descriptionColumn = descriptionColumninput.Value
        duedateColumn = duedateColumninput.Value
    End If

    With .tables(TableNo)
        mTitleRow = startRow
        'copy title
        For eTitleRow = 2 To (.Rows.Count - startRow + 2)
            Cells(eTitleRow, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(mTitleRow, titleColumn).Range.Text)
            mTitleRow = mTitleRow + 1
        Next eTitleRow

        mDescriptionRow = startRow
        'copy description
        For eDescriptionRow = 2 To (.Rows.Count - startRow + 2)
            Cells(eDescriptionRow, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(mDescriptionRow, descriptionColumn).Range.Text)
            mDescriptionRow = mDescriptionRow + 1
        Next eDescriptionRow

        mDueDateRow = startRow
        Dim Pretransform As String
        'copy Due Date
        For eDueDateRow = 2 To (.Rows.Count - startRow + 2)
            Cells(eDueDateRow, 9) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(mDueDateRow, duedateColumn).Range.Text)
            mDueDateRow = mDueDateRow + 1
        Next eDueDateRow

    End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing
UserForm1.Hide
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

End Sub

Private Sub descriptionColumninput_Change()
    descriptionColumn = descriptionColumninput.Value
End Sub

Private Sub duedateColumninput_Change()
    duedateColumn = duedateColumninput.Value
End Sub

Private Sub startRowinput_Change()
    startRow = startRowinput.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TableNoinput_Change()
    TableNo = TableNoinput.Value
End Sub

Private Sub titleColumninput_Change()
    titleColumn = titleColumninput.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: For questions about problems with code you've written, you need to post the code.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why this might be happening is if you have the `Stop` keyword written at the end of your code.

Comment: Okay done. Its the VBA code for my user form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, one reason I can think of why the VBEditor might be opening is if you have the `Stop` keyword in your code somewhere. A thrown error can also open the editor, but you'd be seeing an error dialog before that. Also, programmatic interaction with the editor can open it, but I doubt you're doing that.

If it is an error or the `Stop` keyword, you'll ultimately need to fix the error or remove the keyword to solve your issue. However, you can try using this line of code at the end of your `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
```